# Excel 2007 Sorting and Function

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have combined data from monthly charts over a 12 month period – and have sorted by Acct Name – (see ex. A)

```
Example A:
Rep    Acct Name       Jan     Feb     Mar     Apr     May     Jun     Jul     Aug
AA     Able Moving    34.99
AA     Able Moving            34.99
AA     Able Moving                    34.99
BB     Bond Storage           198.99
BB     Bond Storage                           99.50           99.50
BB     Bond Storage                                   99.50   99.50
BB     Bond Storage                                                           198.99
```

Now,  I need to combine all the values of each acct into one row by month (see ex. B)

```
Example B:
Rep    Acct Name       Jan     Feb     Mar     Apr     May     Jun     Jul     Aug
AA     Able Moving    34.99   34.99   34.99
BB     Bond Storage   198.99                  99.50   99.50   199.00          198.99
```

The actual spreadsheet consists of 3600 rows of data.  How can I do this using Excel’s features (2007) and avoid having to do this one acct at a time?

Comment: You mentioned that you combined data from monthly charts.  What does your original data look like?

Answer (score 2):

Use data filtering to get a list of unique reps/accts: http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-HP010073943.aspx

Then, use a SUMIF function to add up data matching the name on the row you're on.

Answer (score 0):

Use Subtotal and, assuming Rep is in `A1` and no gaps, filter on Rep Contains tot to add =B4 in `B5` and copy down. (But you won't get Example B from Example A - though many thanks to @Scott for making the question intelligible).